# Failure to setup and build IFC.js project with npm

Tags: npm-install, npm-run

I'm triyng to get acquainted with IFC.js API. Starting from the start, I first tried to setup and build step by step the "hello world" [tutorial](https://ifcjs.github.io/info/docs/Guide/web-ifc/Tutorials/Hello%20world/). Installing the last dependancy failed with the following error message :

> npm install @open-wc/building-rollup --save-dev

```
npm ERR! node_modules/rollup
npm ERR!   dev rollup@"^3.10.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer rollup@"^2.11.0" from @open-wc/building-rollup@2.2.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@open-wc/building-rollup
npm ERR!   dev @open-wc/building-rollup@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I tried the command again with "--legacy-peer-deps" as suggested, without success. I finally by-passed this step by forcing this installation (--force). Unfortunately, after completing the setup, and as I could have expected, the app doesn't build at the end.

Any help would be warmly welcome !